# SWIFT 引数の入れ方によってエラーが出たりしますが、原因がよくわかりません。

Tags: swift

UIScrollViewの使い方を勉強していたのですが、
UIImageViewへUIimageを入れる際に、
imageView.image =  myImageと入れればエラー

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

になってしまうのですが、nilになっている箇所などないはずなのですが、
この行を

```
imageView = UIImageView(image: myImage)
```

に変えればエラーになりません。
Optionalでnilにならないようにしたはずなのですが、
nilが発見されたとエラーが出るのですが、何故なんでしょうか。。

```
    //宣言
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    //UIImageを作成
    var myImage = UIImage(named: "aaa.png")
    //UIImageViewにUIImageを入れる　　　　←ココ　＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊
    imageView = UIImageView(image: myImage)
    //imageView.image =  myImage　　コレだとエラーになる。
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Comment: `imageView`が`nil`だから、ということではないですか？（勘違いでしたらすみません。）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var imageView: UIImageView!`という宣言は`Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals`と呼ばれるものですが、これはその名の通りアンラップを暗黙的に行うためのものであって、`Optional`型であることにかわりはありませんから、`imageView`が`nil`でないことを保証するわけではありません。

初期化していなければ`imageView`には`nil`が入ったままですので、当然その状態でアクセスすればランタイムエラーが発生します。

Comment: UIImageView(image:＊＊＊)の形で渡せば、なぜエラーが出ないのは、初期化がまだ完了していない状態で設定をしているとみなされ、

インスタンス化した状態でアクセス
（例でいうとimageView.image = myImageだったり
UISCrollView.frame = view.bounds）
すれば、nilが入っていたことがわかるのでエラーになるということでしょうか。

Comment: @user3688956 `imageView = UIImageView(image: myImage)` は`imageView`への代入ですから、`imageView`になにが入っていてもエラーにはなりません。`imageView.image =  myImage`のように`imageView`のプロパティへの代入をするためには、`imageView`が`nil`でない必要があります。

Comment: よくわかりました、ありがとうございます！！！